# Firestore import/export per API

Tags: java, firebase, google-app-engine, google-cloud-firestore, google-client-login

I'm searching for a way to call the [firestore import/export](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import) functionality programmatically from java code.

What i found so far is that the nice [firestore client library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/tree/master/google-cloud-clients/google-cloud-firestore) does not yet support the import/export calls. But the more low level [rest/grpc api](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rpc/google.firestore.admin.v1beta2#google.firestore.admin.v1beta2.ExportDocumentsRequest) already supports them. Using the [java library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client-services/blob/master/clients/1.26.0/google-api-services-firestore/v1beta1/com/google/api/services/firestore/v1beta1/model/GoogleFirestoreAdminV1beta1ExportDocumentsRequest.java) i tried the following:

```java
Firestore firestoreApi = new Firestore
    .Builder(UrlFetchTransport.getDefaultInstance(), new GsonFactory(), null)
    .setApplicationName(SystemProperty.applicationId.get())
    .build();

GoogleFirestoreAdminV1beta2ImportDocumentsRequest importRequest = new GoogleFirestoreAdminV1beta2ImportDocumentsRequest();
importRequest.setInputUriPrefix(String.format("gs://{}/{}/", BUCKET, image));

GoogleLongrunningOperation operation = firestoreApi
    .projects()
    .databases()
    .importDocuments("projects/" + SystemProperty.applicationId.get() + "/databases/(default)", importRequest)
    .execute();
```

Which sadly ends with missing permissions when run in app engine:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401
{
  "code": 401,
  "errors": [
    {
      "domain": "global",
      "location": "Authorization",
      "locationType": "header",
      "message": "Login Required.",
      "reason": "required"
    }
  ],
  "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
  "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
```

I cannot get the [official way](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#obtaining_credentials_on_app_engine_standard_environment) to login to work, because the firestore builder does not have a method to accept a instance of `AppEngineCredentials`.

I already checked the python client library which also seems not support these methods (yet).
Does anyone have a idea how i can either login with the old rest api or get a client library which supports these methods (some language which runs on app engine please :) )

Thanks for reading!
Carsten

Comment: Here's an example in Node:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/schedule-export. For Java, you can adapt this [Cloud Datastore example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine-java8/datastore-schedule-export).

Comment: @JRLtechwriting Thank you very much! Adopting the datastore example worked! I think the app engine account needs 'Cloud Datastore Import Export Admin' and 'Firebase Admin SDK Administrator Service Agent' But those are minor details.
btw: If you add your comment as answer i will accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adapt this [Cloud Datastore example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine-java8/datastore-schedule-export) for Cloud Firestore. See how they get an access token here:

```
import com.google.appengine.api.appidentity.AppIdentityService;
import com.google.appengine.api.appidentity.AppIdentityServiceFactory;

// Get an access token to authorize export request
      ArrayList<String> scopes = new ArrayList<String>();
      scopes.add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore");
      final AppIdentityService appIdentity = AppIdentityServiceFactory.getAppIdentityService();
      final AppIdentityService.GetAccessTokenResult accessToken =
          AppIdentityServiceFactory.getAppIdentityService().getAccessToken(scopes);
      connection.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken.getAccessToken());
```